# Pix, struct Pix, or PIX in Leptonica

Tags: c, tesseract, leptonica

I've been able to successfully use the "Pix" type with Tesseract (see http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample), yet only "struct Pix" and "PIX" are defined in pix.h (of the Leptonica library). "Pix" (no "struct" keyword) seems to not be defined, but it must be defined *somehwere*.

Searching the headers for "Pix" renders too many matches to browse through for meaning. Does anyone know why "Pix" works?

Comment: You are using C++, not C?

Comment: I'm using both. "Pix" worked fine for C++, but it's unresolvable using similar code in C. I'm having to use "PIX".

Comment: That it is: in C++ you don't need to write "struct A", you can just write "A".

Comment: I never knew that. What a great way to arbitrarily infuse ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Eddy_Em: That it is: in C++ you don't need to write "struct A", you can just write "A".